# Event Info Page error with Joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla, permissions

we've just started using CiviCRM events.  I've followed the process to get the event set up.  I can test-drive the link and it works fine but if I go to the live online registration I get an error page that says I don't have permission to access the page.
I've tried setting the public permission to allowed for "CiviEvent: register for events" to Allowed but it doesn't save when I change the permission.
Any ideas where i need to look for the error.  I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.7 and Joomla! 3.5.1
Thanks
Emma

Answer (score 0):

This is an ACL issue. If users can login, then register it is simpler. 
If you are allowing anonymous users then you have a tiny bit of configuration to do to enable anonymous users.
Have to race out to a client for the day, i can send you info tonight with some screen captures, but also maybe you can look up the instructions in the manuals, it works quite nicely when configured.
CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Access Control

For more reference please give a read https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Also can you just double check that you have the event checked off as a "public event".